# Are there only two items sold in the front corner of Nooks Cranny?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

In the front corner of Nooks Cranny they seem to sell summer items (at least for me, being in the Northern Hemisphere). But it only ever seems to be a retro fan and a surfboard, and they alternate periodically.

Are there any other items they sell in that spot that I am missing? Do I have to do anything to trigger anything different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand, that front spot is meant for seasonal items, and for the current season there are two items that can be bought: the retro fan and the surfboard, as you said. Even more annoying, Nook's will only sell one color of each during the entire season, even though there are several colors available. To get other colors, you'll have to travel to other people's islands and buy from them.